# How to create border around jquery mobile webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm basically trying to create a similar type feel of a mobile webpage to the following image with the same border and margin around the edge of the page:

[image]

If you notice how the entire page is surrounded by some kind of margin to the rest of the page and holds it in place. I'm not sure what is controlling it.

I copied this off the interwebz, but this is how a typical jquery mobile page looks right off the bat:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to add a margin, but what I've realized is I have no idea how to change the CSS to control the actual block itself.

In the jquery mobile page I'm working on now, in order for the "header" to appear, it's shown in code as:

```
<div data-role="header">
```

And then for the whole "page" itself, it's the same except data role and div id is page. Does anyone have experience in jquery mobile to talk about the right way to do this. I would paste the CSS, but I don't even udnerstand this "data role" concept and what it means, I'm used to "id" and "class" and I have no idea how to control the box itself.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want the margin to show even though the page is longer then what can be displayed by the browser?

Comment: You can add a class or id to the div, it won't cause a problem. The `data-` attributes are used by jQuery mobile to enhance your HTML and replace/wrap it with HTML produced by jQuery Mobile.

Comment: yes, it's a very thin margin.. looks like maybe 2 or 3 pixels. i want it to look similar to how it is there with the outside showing that border a little bit to give it a different look since everything is so similar in mobile pages.

Comment: @jeemusu, i added a 15px margin to the page element, which loks like:<div id="page" class="marginout" data-role="page" data-theme="d">, but ti didn't seem to do anything....

Comment: I had a similar problem, in my case I just wanted rounded corners around the edge of the screen (similar to instagram). I found the only way to achieve it in jQueryMobile was to overlay a png with a fixed position on top of the site. Not exactly elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you edit that div from within your script? What about

```
$('div[data-role=header]').addClass('foo');
```

Then you can apply whatever CSS you like to .foo

Comment: how would you close this tag exactly? is the 'foo' just a class somewhere, like on the style sheet it would say, .foo {} ?

Comment: there is also another element besides the data-role:header and it shows the theme. here's the whole page DIV, i'm wondering if it's possible to do this to whole page? <div id="page" data-role="page" data-theme="d">

Comment: i'm not exactly sure what you're asking... you don't know how to write CSS? your div already has an ID, so to apply styles to it, you don't even need my code, just use #page {background:red} - or whatever styles you want to apply